# How to open and edit server.properties (in kafka)

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

I am running in my locahost both Zookeeper and Kafka (1 instance each).

I create succesfully a topic from kafka:

[image]

I want to change server.properties (in kafka) but I don't open by nano:

```
nano server.properties
```

-> `/bin/sh: nano: not found`

How to open and edit server.properties in kafka ? Any suggestion, please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Do you have `vi` on it?

Comment: How about install nano, then?

Comment: This question is about installing `nano` and has nothing to do with Kafka

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check what editors are avaliable in the system; then add one of them to be used as default, eg.:

```sh
echo 'EDITOR=vi' >> ~/.bashrc
```

then reload .bashrc via:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

and you can check:

```sh
printenv|grep EDITOR
```

then you can edit properties in 'vi' which should be avaliable in system, or just install nano as suggested previously.